# Resize image without upscaling

Tags: java, swing, geometry

I have following image

[image: Image to resize]

Now I want to resize it to paint as background for a label, so that the borders still have the original size.

Here ist the code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

/**
 * <code>BackgroundTest</code>.
 */
public class BackgroundTest extends JLabel {

    // probably you need to download it and change the URL
    private static final Image BACKGROUND = read(
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIwyR.png");

    private static Image read(String url) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(new URL(url));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot resolve image!", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(scaleRect(BACKGROUND, new Insets(7, 7, 7, 7), getWidth(), getHeight()), 0, 0, this);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(BackgroundTest::startUp);
    }

    private static void startUp() {
        BackgroundTest label = new BackgroundTest();
        label.setOpaque(false);
        label.setText("<html>Simple multiline test to check<br>the painting</html>");
        label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(7, 7, 7, 7));
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(BACKGROUND)));
        frm.add(panel);
        frm.setSize(300, 300);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Image scaleRect(Image src, Insets safePart, int width, int height) {
        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();

        g.drawImage(src, 0, 0, width, height, this);
        g.dispose();
        return result;
    }
}
```

The result looks ugly, because the borders are upscaled:

[image: Ugly result]

In this code example I only need a correct implementation of the function `scaleRect`, so that it considers the border insets (`safePart` parameter). The `Graphics2D` class has some other `drawImage` methods, but I don't know how to use them to achieve my goal.

Comment: Maybe just use a custom `Border` on the label instead of trying to scale the image.

Comment: @camickr yeah, it's my last chance. But only the last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the [9-patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch) image approach - basically split your image into 9 pieces, some of which can be stretched without any visual artifacts and some that will stay at fixed size.

Basically cut it along these lines:

[image]

Then you can stretch:

- top center & bottom center ones horizontally (if needed)
- left center & right center ones vertically (if needed)
- middle one can be stretched both horizontally and vertically
- corners should remain in fixed sizes, otherwise you will get artifacts

Also you don't really need to cut the image, you can simply paint a specific part of the image:

```java
public class SampleComponent extends JLabel
{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent ( final Graphics g )
    {
        final Graphics2D g2d = ( Graphics2D ) g;

        final Image image = ...; // Your image
        g2d.drawImage (
                image,
                dstX1, dstY1, dstX2, dstY2,
                imgX1, imgY1, imgX2, imgY2,
                null
        );

        super.paintComponent ( g );
    }
}
```

- `dst*` - are the drawing destination rectangle coordinates
- `img*` - are the coordinates of rectangle on your image

Note that this approach will only work with images that you can actually be split like shown above, it obviously won't work for something like photos or paintings, but for those cases I don't know why would you want to upscale them in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to @MikleGarin for the idea. Here is the complete solution:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

/**
 * <code>BackgroundTest</code>.
 */
public class BackgroundTest extends JLabel {

    // probably you need to download it and change the URL
    private static final Image BACKGROUND = read(
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIwyR.png");

    private static Image read(String url) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(new URL(url));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot resolve image!", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(scaleRect(BACKGROUND, new Insets(7, 7, 7, 7), getWidth(), getHeight()), 0, 0, this);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(BackgroundTest::startUp);
    }

    private static void startUp() {
        BackgroundTest label = new BackgroundTest();
        label.setOpaque(false);
        label.setText("<html>Simple multiline test to check<br>the painting</html>");
        label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(7, 7, 7, 7));
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(BACKGROUND)));
        frm.add(panel);
        frm.setSize(300, 300);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Image scaleRect(Image src, Insets safePart, int width, int height) {
        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();

        int srcWidth = src.getWidth(null);
        int srcHeight = src.getHeight(null);
        // top left
        g.drawImage(src, 0, 0, safePart.left, safePart.right, 0, 0, safePart.left, safePart.top, null);
        // top center
        g.drawImage(src, safePart.left, 0, width - safePart.right, safePart.top, safePart.left, 0,
                srcWidth - safePart.right, safePart.top, null);
        // top right
        g.drawImage(src, width - safePart.right, 0, width, safePart.top, srcWidth - safePart.right, 0,
                srcWidth, safePart.top, null);
        // center left
        g.drawImage(src, 0, safePart.top, safePart.left, height - safePart.bottom, 0, safePart.top,
                safePart.left, srcHeight - safePart.bottom, null);
        // center
        g.drawImage(src, safePart.left, safePart.top, width - safePart.right, height - safePart.bottom, safePart.left, safePart.top,
                srcWidth - safePart.right, srcHeight - safePart.bottom, null);
        // center right
        g.drawImage(src, width - safePart.right, safePart.top, width, height - safePart.bottom, srcWidth - safePart.right, safePart.top,
                srcWidth, srcHeight - safePart.bottom, null);
        // bottom left
        g.drawImage(src, 0, height - safePart.bottom, safePart.left, height, 0, srcHeight - safePart.bottom, safePart.left, srcHeight,
                null);
        // bottom middle
        g.drawImage(src, safePart.left, height - safePart.bottom, width - safePart.right, height, safePart.left,
                srcHeight - safePart.bottom, srcWidth - safePart.right, srcHeight, null);
        // bottom right
        g.drawImage(src, width - safePart.right, height - safePart.bottom, width, height, srcWidth - safePart.right,
                srcHeight - safePart.bottom, srcWidth, srcHeight, null);
        g.dispose();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now it looks as it was required:

[image: Correct Border]